pytest question - how to do an assert_call_count for a called module
Below are the files I used for my testing:

logging.txt file


# Jan 20 05:22:08 [INFO] Completed running task 72611
# Feb 20 03:22:08 [ERROR] Completed running task 72613
# Feb 23 04:00:08 [ERROR] Completed running task 72653
# Mar 25 04:01:08 [ERROR] Completed running task 72693
# Apr 29 05:22:09 [ERROR] Task 72619 failure: Could not locate filehandle to datafile



error_logging.py


import re

lines_already_read = set()

def parse_line(line):
    # Lines are formatted like this:
    # Jan 20 05:22:08 [INFO] Completed running task 72618
    # Jan 20 05:22:09 [ERROR] Task 72619 failure: Could not locate filehandle to datafile

    results = re.search(r'\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})', line).groups()
    # then use results.groups() to unpactk the values
    hour, min =  results

    if not (('02' <= hour <= '03' ) or (hour == '04' and min == '00')):
        print(line, end='')
        # Explicitly access global list
        lines_already_read.add(line)


def main_logic():
    with open('logging.txt') as log:
        for line in log:
            if  '[ERROR]' in line and line not in lines_already_read:
                parse_line(line)


def test_main_logic():
    main_logic()
    assert len(lines_already_read) == 2   # there are two entries in lines_already_read


# Executes when script is run
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_logic()


So my error_logging.py file shows that I have two methods: main_logic and parse_line.
The test actually ran fine but I am trying to add another  assert statement in the test_main_logic function  to assert the call_count for the parse_line function , which is called my the main_logic() function - how do I do that correctly?
